# Future not completed on PostgreSQL + Dart

Tags: postgresql, dart

I have got follow code:

```
void main() async {
  connection = PostgreSQLConnection('localhost', 5432, 'db', username: 'postgres', password: '12345');
  await connection.open();
  
  //... 
  // some http handler that have next code inside:
  List<List<dynamic>> result = await connection.query(body['sql']).timeout(Duration(seconds: 90));
```

If I run a lot of queries to http handler I am getting error:

```
TimeoutException after 0:00:30.000000: Future not completed
```

It's very strange, because on `query` I have timeout `90 seconds`. So it's happens on `connection`. But I am opening connection only once in `main`.

Could anybody explain how it's happens? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQLConnection has parameters: **timeoutInSeconds** and **queryTimeoutInSeconds** and they both default to 30. I suggest you use them instead of timeout of Future.

Comment: "instead of timeout of Future." could you explain more detail? Why I should not use Future timeout here?

Comment: Postgres driver has internal timeouts (timeoutInSeconds, queryTimeoutInSeconds) and they times out faster than yours, because they are 30 seconds by default, while yours is 90. So you will need to increase those. And when you do that there is no need to use your Future's one.

Comment: But which one timeouts do I need? And what difference between `connection` and `query` timeouts?

Comment: connection timeout is used when driver opens connection to Postgres. Query timeout is used when you are performing query. From your example I am assuming that you need to use query timeout.